# Request URL until required data arrives

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is the best way to periodically request URL and cancel requests when required data is present in the response in plain Javascript?

Say, I am requesting `posts` URI that returns JSON and want to cancel requests when `numberOfPosts` attribute in response is equal than some `N`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) with your web service call and cancel the interval once you got the expected response via [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

MDN about `setInterval()`:

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. Returns an `intervalID`.

Comment: Is there cleaner/better way to do this? I know that I can do `clearInterval(intervalID)` inside `setInterval` callback, but sometimes `setInterval` does extra requests when `delay` value is small.

Comment: Increase the `delay`, or implement your own solution using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: You mean calling `setTimeout` in `setTimeout` callback and cancelling it on success?

Comment: Either that, or setting the timeout after you got the negative result back. Depending on how exact your timeout should be, this would solve the issue with duplicate calls.

Comment: OK, I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is demonstration of `setInterval` approach from accepted answer that worked for me (`getJSONResponse` contains all request handling logic):

```
var POLL_INTERVAL = 50;
var URI = 'posts'; 
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  var response = getJSONResponse(URI);
  if (response.numberOfPosts === N) {
    // Process response
    ... 
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}, POLL_INTERVAL);
```